# API Gateway generated SDK issue: "No such host is known"

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I generated a Java SDK via the API Gateway and created a Maven project with this as a dependency.

When I run the app to hit one of the APIs it throws the following error:

`

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: No such host is known (******.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1189)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1135)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:784)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:752)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:726)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:668)
    at com.amazonaws.client.ClientHandlerImpl.doInvoke(ClientHandlerImpl.java:204)
    at com.amazonaws.client.ClientHandlerImpl.invoke(ClientHandlerImpl.java:185)
    at com.amazonaws.client.ClientHandlerImpl.execute(ClientHandlerImpl.java:93)
    at com.amazonaws.opensdk.protect.client.SdkClientHandler.execute(SdkClientHandler.java:42)
    at com.pps.configuration.api.ConfigurationClient.getAllProductClasses(ConfigurationClient.java:103)
    at connection.main(MainClass.java:25)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: No such host is known (******.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com)
    at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1515)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:848)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1505)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1364)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1298)
    at com.amazonaws.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:27)
    at com.amazonaws.http.DelegatingDnsResolver.resolve(DelegatingDnsResolver.java:38)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:112)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:374)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionManagerFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionManagerFactory.java:76)
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy3.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1311)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1127)
```

`

I've tried rebuilding the SDK, but still no fix.

Comment: Did you deploy your api into Stage?

Comment: This error usually occurs when the hostname specified in the request is not valid or cannot be resolved. To resolve this issue, make sure that the hostname is correct and can be resolved by the DNS server. Additionally, check that the network connection is working properly and that the hostname is accessible from the machine where the request is being made.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.